# Selecting data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I having a problem

i want to select users with status yes

but if there no users with status yes display users with status calm or eaz

```
table users 

    id users  status
    1  Fred   yes
    2  Tom    calm
    3  Ken    yes
    4  Joe    calm
    5  Steve  eaz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use In a WHERE Clause also an CASE WHEN condtion

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `users` VARCHAR(5),
>   `status` VARCHAR(4)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO users
>   (`id`, `users`, `status`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Fred', 'yes'),
>   ('2', 'Tom', 'calm'),
>   ('3', 'Ken', 'yes'),
>   ('4', 'Joe', 'calm'),
>   ('5', 'Steve', 'eaz');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
> CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE `status` = 'yes') > 0 THEN `status` = 'yes'
> ELSE `status` = 'eaz' OR `status` = 'calm' END
> ```
>
> ```
> id | users | status
> -: | :---- | :-----
>  1 | Fred  | yes   
>  3 | Ken   | yes
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bdc9855648bcd47672d6c9e199a57c41)*

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `not exists` and boolean logic:

```
select u.*
from users u
where 
    status = 'yes'
    or (
        status in ('calm', 'eaz')
        and not exists (select 1 from users where status = 'yes')
    )
```

In MySQL 8.0, you could also uses window functions:

```
select *
from (select u.*, max(status = 'yes') over() has_yes_status from users u) u
where 
    status = 'yes'
    or (status in ('calm', 'eaz') and has_yes_status = 0)
```